# INSERT ... SELECT Syntax issue when value(s) from two or more different query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table name **shop_balance**. which has 3 columns
 (**shop_balance_id**(INT,PK),
  **shop_balance**(DOUBLE),
 **balance_date**(DATE)).

For  **shop_balance**(DOUBLE) column I use two sub query.
1.Get last shop balance amount row  **shop_balance** column in **shop_balance** table.
2.Get purchase amount after one purchase product(s).
and finally I subtract them and get current shop balance

My query is here

```
INSERT INTO shop_balance 
SELECT null,
(
    (SELECT shop_balance FROM shop_balance 
     WHERE 
     shop_balance_id=(SELECT MAX(shop_balance_id) FROM shop_balance)
    ) 
        -
    (
    SELECT 
        SUM(pr_pur_cost_price*quantity) AS net FROM product_purchase_item AS i
    LEFT JOIN 
        product_purchases AS p
    ON 
        p.product_purchase_item_id=i.product_purchase_item_id
    WHERE 
        p.insert_operation=$id
    GROUP by 
        p.insert_operation
    )
),curdate();
```

It is clear that the two sub query are different condition and no direct relation them. Above `INSERT` query is work well. But is it good idea to use many sub query without `INSERT ... SELECT` Syntax for `INSERT` one value? If not, how can I convert to `INSERT ... SELECT` Syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do the calculation the way you do the calculation.  I am guessing that a trigger might better meet your needs, but doing the logic in an `insert` is fine.

The following slightly simplifies your query.  It eliminates the double subquery on `shop_balance`, changes the `left join` to an inner join (you have a condition on the second table), and eliminates the `group by` from the second subquery:

```
INSERT INTO shop_balance 
    SELECT null,
           ((SELECT shop_balance
             FROM shop_balance 
             ORDER BY shop_balance_id desc
             LIMIT 1
            ) -
            (SELECT SUM(pr_pur_cost_price*quantity) AS net
             FROM product_purchase_item i JOIN 
                  product_purchases p
                  ON p.product_purchase_item_id=i.product_purchase_item_id
             WHERE p.insert_operation=$id
           )
          ), curdate();
```

You should also list the columns in the `insert` clause, and probably eliminate the first `NULL` (it would be set to NULL by default).  The final `curdate()` suggests that you might want an automatic column to store the insertion time as well.

Comment: but why you eliminate `group by`. the insert_operation is not unique and it's a track number of different purchase history. so if I dont use `group by`. how it will sum  every purchase time?

Comment: @coder . . . The query is grouping by the same field used in the `where` clause.  The `sum()` makes this an aggregation query, not the `group by`.  Plus, the presence of `group by` suggests (to me) that multiple groups are being generated.  However, the query would generate an error if the subquery returned more than one row.